# How can I rename a sequence of files without front zero padding so they can have front zero padding?

Tags: linux, command-line

I have a sequence of files:

```
file0.png, file1.png, ..., file10.png,... file100.png, ..., file1000.png, file1001.png, ..., file10000.png
```

I want to make a video with ffmpeg,

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -pattern_type glob -i '*.png' -c:v libx264 out.mp4
```

The name convention leads to a wrong order of the files read in input. How can I solve this?

the so-called solution "How do I rename a bunch of files in the Command Prompt?" doesn't works!

Comment: Your ffmpeg command line references: <BLOCKQUOTE>-pattern_type glob -i '*.png'</BLOCKQUOTE> That could have ffmpeg using whatever order it wants (presumably even random).  See if, instead, you can specify every file on the command line, or if you can specify a list of files sent via standard input, or if you can specify a text file that contains a list of filenames. (The @ is used by many programs for the latter approach.) Any of those approach will lead to a solution using the references mentioned in other comments. Possibly helpful: echo $( for x in $( seq -w 1 10 ); do echo file${x}; done )

Comment: Actually, that prior example  may work in Linux, not Windows or even BSD.  You specified "command-line", but didn't specify what OS you are asking about.  (I believe ffmmpeg is multi-platform.)  If you seek further help, specify what OS you're using (and what questions you have remaining).

Comment: @TOOGAM im using linux, i thought superuser was for linux

Comment: That makes it much easier to do. Try this: [Renaming hundreds of files at once for proper sorting](http://askubuntu.com/questions/473236/renaming-hundreds-of-files-at-once-for-proper-sorting). I suggest that you start with the accepted answer.

Comment: @karel i tried `rename 's/\d+/sprintf("%05d", $&)/e' *.png` but didn't worked. could you explain to me each part of this command, maybe there is something to change...

Comment: @karel i tried the example with prefix, the example doesn't work neither

Comment: @karel, ok it's because archlinux has some problem with the rename util. I boot on a live ubuntu, and did the rename. THX

Answer (score 4):

> Because archlinux has some problem with the rename util, I booted on a live Ubuntu, and did the rename.

```
rename 's/\d+/sprintf("%05d", $&)/e' *.png
```

This is what toto did to rename the sequence of files.

Answer (score 0):

Initially I looked at `ffmpeg`'s docs to see if input filenames can be specified in a file of its own, where you could sort them as you like. But the documentation didn't clearly have an option like that. I could be wrong, and that would be my recommendation if you notice such an option.

So instead you should rename your files for input in the order you want. I'll assume you are using the bash shell, the files are in the same directory, all named `file1.png` to `file10000.png` and you'd prefer to have them named `file00001.png` to `file10000.png`.

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in file*.png
do
  printf -v n "file%05d.png" "${f:4:-4}"
  mv "$f" "$n"
done
```

On one line as:
`for f in file*.png; do printf -v n "file%05d.png" "${f:4:-4}"; mv "$f" "$n"; done`

or maybe just:

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( i=0; i<10000; i++ ))
do
  printf -v n "%05d" $i
  mv "file$i.png" "file$n.png"
done
```

On one line as:
`for (( i=0; i<10000; i++ )); do printf -v n "%05d" $i; mv "file$i.png" "file$n.png"; done;`

I'm not sure which is faster, but I suspect the second one would be.